# Flutter/Dart - Dynamic value in a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a variable with dynamic value in it. Something like this:

```
String myAlphabet = 'c';
List myList = [
   'a',
   'b',
   getMyAlphabet()
];

String getMyAlphabet(){
   return myAlphabet;
}
```

When I access myList, I should get ['a','b','c']. But at one point of my program, the value of myAlpabet is changed to 'd'. At that point when I access myList I should be getting ['a','b','d'] but instead I'm still getting ['a','b','c'].

How do I make it so that everytime I access myList, I will be getting the latest value instead of the value when it is first initialized? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... How about you use making a method to get a my List?

```
//
​
//

void main() {
  String myAlphabet = 'c';
  String getMyAlphabet(){
    return myAlphabet;
  }
  
  List<String> getMyList() {
    return [
      'a',
      'b',
      getMyAlphabet()
    ];
  }
  
  List myList = [
    'a',
    'b',
    getMyAlphabet()
  ];


  print(myList);
  print(getMyList());
  
  myAlphabet = 'd';
  
  print(myList);
  print(getMyList());
  

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```dart
List myList = [
   'a',
   'b',
   getMyAlphabet()
];
```

`getMyAlphabet()` will be evaluated at the time that this `List` is created, and the *result* will be stored in the `List`.

If you want `myList` to always return a `List` with the latest evaluation of `getMyAlphabet()`, you could make `myList` create and return a new `List` each time by making it a getter function:

```dart
List get myList => ['a', 'b', getMyAlphabet()];
```

Note that you wouldn't be able to effectively *mutate* `myList`, which potentially could be surprising to callers.

Another approach would be to make `myList` a list of [*thunks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) so that they would need an extra level of evaluation:

```dart
List<String Function()> myList = [
  () => 'a',
  () => 'b',
  getMyAlphabet,
];

var a = myList[0]();
var lastElement = myList.last();
var list = [for (var thunk in myList) thunk()];
```

To take it further, you could create your own `List`-like class whose `operator[]` implementation invokes each thunk automatically instead of making callers do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to edit the List rather than try to create a "pointer" in the list, which I don't believe is possible with Dart.

`List` has a method called `replaceRange` ([docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/replaceRange.html)) which you could use to replace a value at a certain index in the list.  There are other methods you could combine to do the same thing.